# Static variables work differently in Apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
VF Page
<apex:page controller="StaticTestOne">
   <apex:form >        
       <apex:commandButton id="smtng" action="{!someaction}" value="save"/>
   </apex:form> 
{!someoutput} 
</apex:page>

Controller:

public class StaticTestOne {
public String someoutput{get;set;}
public String someoutput2{get;set;}
public static String varone;
public StaticTestOne(){
    varone='1';
    someoutput2='smthg';
}
public void someaction(){                
    someoutput=varone;
    //someoutput=someoutput2;
}
}
```

Why am I able to see the commented line someoutput2 working(if un-commented) and varone not working?

I mean from the above code we should see 1 but we don't. 
Can you please explain how static variables work?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static variable values only have a lifetime of an individual request. Values that you want to preserve from when a page is generated over to when data is posted back need to be non-`transient` and non-`static`. This approach allows the original page generation and the post back to run on different CPUs, helping the platform to scale and be reliable.

For your case, the `StaticTestOne` constructor runs as part of the page generation but is not run when values are posted back via `apex:commandButton`, leaving `varone` with its default `null` value. The controller state is deserialized from the view state rather than a new instance of the controller being created.

See [Order of Execution in a Visualforce Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm) for some related detail.

Comment: To be pedantic, if you bind a static or transient variable to an apex:inputHidden (or other type), you can preserve the value across transactions, but that's more of an advanced technique.